# How do I resolve fatal errors while trying to setup Updraft in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

While I am trying to set up Updraft Plus, for backup reasons I get this message:

> PHP Fatal error (TypeError) has occurred during save settings. Error
> Message: array_diff(): Argument #2 must be of type array, bool given
> (Code: 0, line 39 in
> /home/www/emprime/emprimevintage.com/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/vendor/otgs/installer/includes/upgrade/AutoUpgrade.php)

I am new to WordPress and coding so it is very difficult for me to resolve this problem. The site was made by somebody else and I can't come in contact with him.

Can anybody help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you posted shows that there is some issue with the plugin called **"WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency with WPML"** try deactivating that plugin and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue, can you tell me what error you're getting after deactivating that plugin?

Comment: I deactivate the plugin "WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency with WPML" and then tried again to set up the Updraft Plus plugin and the error appeared. Τhe error is:PHP Fatal error (TypeError) has occurred during save settings. Error Message: array_diff(): Argument #2 must be of type array, bool given (Code: 0, line 39 in /home/www/emprime/emprimevintage.com/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-multilingual/vendor/otgs/installer/includes/upgrade/AutoUpgrade.php)

Answer (score 0):

As found here: https://wpml.org/errata/php8-fatal-error-uncaught-typeerror-array_diff-argument-2-must-be-of-type-array/

Overview of the issue
If you are running a server with PHP8, whenever you try to activate the Enable auto-updates option in Dashboard → Plugins, you will get the following error:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_diff(): Argument #2 must be of type array, bool given in …/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/vendor/otgs/installer/includes/upgrade/AutoUpgrade.php:39

Workaround
As a workaround:

1. Go to Dashboard → Plugins.
2. Disable WPML Multilingual CMS.
3. Activate the Enable auto-updates option. (I did it for Updraftplus
   plugin)
4. Re-enable WPML.

It worked for me, then I could save the settings for Updraftplus.